# How to debug using stdout during Pytest execution

Tags: python, pycharm, stdout, pytest

I am trying to debug a feature of a test (that runs on pytest)
I am setting a debug point and stop there (using Pycharm)
However, I cannot debug efficiently the code because my stdout and stderr are redirected since this is a pytest. I tried [restoring stdout from `sys.__stdout__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777152/unable-to-restore-stdout-to-original-only-to-terminal) but `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` did not work.

Is there any way to restore stdout in order to debug?

This is not a duplicate of [python-pytest-capturing-stdout-always-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201912/python-pytest-capturing-stdout-always-fails), capturing std is not failing in my case, it's captured at a location that is not really helping me to debug...

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html - I have used the -s option before and it worked for me. Try it out.

Comment: Otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201912/python-pytest-capturing-stdout-always-fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pytest: capturing stdout always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201912/python-pytest-capturing-stdout-always-fails)

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code with sys.stdout redirection? Do you use virtualenv in PyCharm or debugging in local environment?

Comment: @DemetriOS: -s worked :) If someone answers it, I ll accept that answer :) I don't think its a duplicate since Its not that the output is not printed, as in the link, its that it does not go to the output and I cannot see it to debug... Also -s is not proposed as a solution (since i think it can't solve that question)

Comment: @ntg answered it. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize the -s option while running pytest.  As shown here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html.
The -s option disables all capturing of stdout.